Number of strings with an even number of consecutive pairs
Given $N_A$ A's and $N_B$ B's, how many words of length $n=N_A+N_B$ have an even number of consecutive B-pairs. A consecutive B-pair is when there are 2 B's next to each other in the word. For example for words with 2 A's and 3 B's we have
AABBB: 2 pairs
ABABB: 1 pair
ABBAB: 1 pair
ABBBA: 2 pairs
BAABB: 1 pair
BABAB: no pairs
BABBA: 1 pair
BBAAB: 1 pair
BBABA: 1 pair
BBBAA: 2 pairs
So in total we have 4 words with an even number of consecutive B-pairs. I am wondering what the best strategy is to calculate this number and if there exists a general expression for an arbitrary number of A's and B's.
EDIT:
using lulu's approach I came up with the following:
Denote $q(N_A,N_B,p)$ as the number of words with $N_A$ A's, $N_B$ B's and parity $p$ ($p=1$ if there is an even number of pairs and $-1$ if there are an odd number of pairs). Then
\begin{equation}
q(N_A,N_B,p) = q(N_A-1,N_B,p) + \sum_{k=1}^{N_B}q(N_A-1,N_B-k,(-1)^{k+1}p).
\end{equation}
Furthermore we have
\begin{equation}
q(N_A,N_B,1)+q(N_A,N_B,-1)=\binom{N}{N_A}.
\end{equation}
Additionally we have the initial condition $q(0,0,1) = 1 $. This recursion seems to be rather unpractical to solve.

Any good word begins with a block of the form $B^kA$ where $k$ might be $0$.  This block contains $k-1$ $B-$pairs (if $k>0$, if $k=0$ then it contains no $B-$pairs).  What's left is then a shorter word which is either good or bad depending on the parity of $k$, so you can set up a recursion.

If instead $s(N_A,N_B,p)$ denotes the words, which contain exactly $p$ pairs of $B$ , then a simpler recursive formula holds: $$s(N_A,N_B,p) = s(N_A,N_B-1,p-1) + s(N_A-1,N_B,p) + s(N_A-1,N_B-1,p) - s(N_A-1,N_B-1,p-1).$$ I am unsure if this is of any help for your question however, as you would need to then sum $s(N_A,N_B,p)$ over all even $p$.

You could also try to sum the recursive formula I have written over all odd $p$, and you would get a (simpler) recursive formula for your function $q(N_A,N_B,1)$.

nice question ..... +1

Here is another approach using generating functions. We consider a binary alphabet built from letters $A,B$. Words which do not have any consecutive equal letters are called Smirnov words. A generating function for Smirnov words is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{Az}{1+Az}-\frac{Bz}{1+Bz}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The coefficient $[z^n]$ of $z^n$ in the series (1) gives the number of binary words of length $n$ which do not have any consecutive letters.

In the current problem, we are looking for words of length $n=N_A+N_B$ which consist of $N_A$ letters $A$ but do not have any further restriction on the letters $A$. The letters $B$ can occur only in runs with odd length which means that besides single occurrences of the letter $B$ only even pairs of consecutive $B$s are admissible. We encode this situation as
\begin{align*}
Az\quad&\to\quad Az+\left(Az\right)^2+\left(Az\right)^3+\cdots=\frac{Az}{1-Az}\\
Bz\quad&\to\quad Bz+\left(Bz\right)^3+\left(Bz\right)^5+\cdots=\frac{Bz}{1-(Bz)^2}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

Putting (2) into (1) we derive the generating function
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{G(z;A,B)}&=\left(1-\frac{\frac{Az}{1-Az}}{1+\frac{Az}{1-Az}}-\frac{\frac{Bz}{1-(Bz)^2}}{1+\frac{Bz}{1-(Bz)^2}}\right)^{-1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1+Bz-B^2z^2}{1-B^2z^2-Az\left(1+Bz-B^2z^2\right)}}\tag{3}\\
&=1 + (A + B)z + (A^2 + 2 AB) z^2+ (A^3 + 3 A^2 B + A B^2 + B^3)z^3\\
&\qquad + (A^4 + 4 A^3 B + 3 A^2 B^2 + 2 AB^3) z^4\\
&\qquad + (A^5 + 5 A^4 B + 6 A^3 B^2 + {\color{blue}{4 A^2 B^3}} + 2 A B^4 + B^5) z^5\\
&\qquad+ \cdots
\end{align*}
The last line was calculated with the help of WolframAlpha
. Note the blue marked term $\color{blue}{4 A^2 B^3}$ with coefficient $4$ corresponds nicely with the four valid words in OPs list.

The wanted number of arrangements is the coefficient of $A^{N_A}B^{N_B}z^{N_A+N_B}$ from the generating function $G(z;A,B)$ in (3). Since the coefficient of $A^{N_A}$ can be easily isolated, we start with it first. We obtain from (3)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[A^{N_A}]G(z;A,B)}
&=[A^{N_A}]\frac{1+Bz-B^2z^2}{1-B^2z^2-Az\left(1+Bz-B^2z^2\right)}\tag{4.1}\\
&=[A^{N_A}]\frac{1+Bz-B^2z^2}{1-B^2z^2}
\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}(Az)^q\frac{\left(1+Bz-B^2z^2\right)^{q}}{\left(1-B^2z^2\right)^{q}}\\
&=[A^{N_A}]\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}(Az)^q\frac{\left(1+Bz-B^2z^2\right)^{q+1}}{\left(1-B^2z^2\right)^{q+1}}\tag{4.2}\\
&=\frac{\left(1+Bz-B^2z^2\right)^{N_A+1}}{\left(1-B^2z^2\right)^{N_A+1}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(1+\frac{Bz}{1-B^2z^2}\right)^{N_A+1}}\tag{4.3}
\end{align*}

Comment:

In (4.1) we factor out $\frac{1}{1-B^zz^2}$ and use the geometric series expansion.

In (4.2) we select the coefficient of $A^{N_A}$.



The wanted number of admissible words can be derived from $(4.3)$ by calculating $[z^{N_B}]$. We can also set $B=1$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[z^{N_B}]}&\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^{N_A+1}}\\
&=[z^{N_B}]\sum_{k=0}^{N_A+1}\binom{N_A+1}{k}\left(\frac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^k\\
&=[z^{N_B}]\sum_{k=0}^{N_A+1}\binom{N_A+1}{k}z^k\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{-k}{l}\left(-z^2\right)^l\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\min{N_A+1,N_B}}\binom{N_A+1}{k}[z^{N_B-k}]\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+l-1}{l}z^{2l}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

In the last line we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]Q(z)=[z^p]z^qQ(z)$ and use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$. We observe in (5) that we have to select the coefficient from even powers $z^{2l}$. This implies that depending on the parity of $N_B$ we have to select either odd or even $k$. We therefore consider two cases.
$N_B$ even: We consider even $N_B$
\begin{align*}
N_B=2N^{\prime}_B\equiv 0(2)
\end{align*}
and have therefore $2N^{\prime}_B-2k=2l$. We obtain from (5) by replacing $k$ with $2k$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[z^{N_B}]}&\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^{N_A+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\min\{N_A+1,N_B\}}\binom{N_A+1}{2k}[z^{2N^{\prime}_B-2k}]
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k+l-1}{l}z^{2l}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\min\{N_A+1,N_B\}}\binom{N_A+1}{2k}
\binom{N^{\prime}_B+k-1}{N^{\prime}_B-k}}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
In the last line we select the coefficient of $z^{2N^{\prime}_B-2k}$ noting that $l=N^{\prime}_B-k$.
$N_B$ odd: We consider odd $N_B$
\begin{align*}
N_B=2N^{\prime}_B+1\equiv 1(2)
\end{align*}
and have therefore $\left(2N^{\prime}_B+1\right)-(2k+1)=2N^{\prime}_B-2k=2l$. We obtain from (5) by replacing $k$ with $2k+1$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[z^{N_B}]}&\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^{N_A+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\min\{N_A+1,N_B\}}\binom{N_A+1}{2k+1}[z^{2N^{\prime}_B-2k}]
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k+l}{l}z^{2l}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\min\{N_A+1,N_B\}}\binom{N_A+1}{2k+1}
\binom{N^{\prime}_B+k}{N^{\prime}_B-k}}\tag{7}
\end{align*}
In the last line we select the coefficient of $z^{2N^{\prime}_B-2k}$ noting that again $l=N^{\prime}_B-k$.
Conclusion: Depending on the parity of $N_B$ the number of valid words is given by the formulas (6) and (7).
OP's example: We have $N_A=2, N_B=3$ and $n=N_A+N_B=5$. We derive from (7)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\min\{N_A+1,N_B\}}}&\color{blue}{\binom{N_A+1}{2k+1}
\binom{N^{\prime}_B+k}{N^{\prime}_B-k}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{1}\binom{3}{2k+1}\binom{k+1}{1-k}
=\binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{0}=3+1\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=4}
\end{align*}
Note: Smirnov words can be found for instance in example III.24 in  Analytic Combinatorics by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

(+1). I have taken the liberty to contribute a basic answer using first principles.

Encoding the problem statement we get from first principles the
generating function with $z$ counting $B$ pairs
$$\frac{1}{1-A} \times \sum_{q\ge 0}
\left[ \frac{B}{1-zB} \frac{A}{1-A} \right]^q
\times \left[ 1 + B + \frac{zB^2}{1-zB} \right]
\\ = \frac{1}{1-A} \times \sum_{q\ge 0}
\left[ \frac{B^q}{(1-zB)^q} \frac{A^q}{(1-A)^q} \right]
\times \left[ 1 + B + \frac{zB^2}{1-zB} \right].$$
Extracting the coefficient on $[A^{N_A}]$
$$\sum_{q\ge 0} {N_A\choose q}
\left[ \frac{B^q}{(1-zB)^q} \right]
\times \left[ 1 + B + \frac{zB^2}{1-zB} \right]
\\ = \left[1+ \frac{B}{1-zB}\right]^{N_A}
\times \left[ 1 + B + \frac{zB^2}{1-zB} \right].$$
We get two pieces when we extract the contribution where $z$ is raised
to an even power, the first is
$$\frac{1}{2} \left[1+ \frac{B}{1-B}\right]^{N_A}
\times \left[ 1 + B + \frac{B^2}{1-B} \right]
= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{1-B} \right]^{N_A+1}.$$
Extract the coefficient on $[B^{N_B}]$ to get
$$\frac{1}{2} {N_A+N_B\choose N_A}.$$
The second piece is
$$\frac{1}{2} [B^{N_B}] \left[1+ \frac{B}{1+B}\right]^{N_A}
\times \left[ 1 + B - \frac{B^2}{1+B} \right]
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [B^{N_B}]
\left[ 1 + B - \frac{B^2}{1+B} \right]
\sum_{q=0}^{N_A} {N_A\choose q} \frac{B^q}{(1+B)^q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^{N_A} {N_A\choose q}
(-1)^{N_B-q} {N_B-2\choose q-2}
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^{N_A} {N_A\choose q}
(-1)^{N_B-q} {N_B-2\choose q}.$$
Writing in terms of extractors,
$$\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{N_B} [w^{N_B}] (1+w)^{N_B-2} (1-w)^{N_A}
- \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{N_B} [w^{N_B-2}] (1+w)^{N_B-2} (1-w)^{N_A}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{N_B} [w^{N_B}]
(1-w^2) (1+w)^{N_B-2} (1-w)^{N_A}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{N_B} [w^{N_B}]
(1+w)^{N_B-1} (1-w)^{N_A+1}.$$
Collecting everything,
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2} {N_A+N_B\choose N_A}
+ \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{N_B}
\sum_{q=0}^{N_B} {N_A+1\choose q} (-1)^q {N_B-1\choose q-1}.}$$
The underlying assumptions are documented in the code below.

with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(NA, NB)
option remember;
local comb, res, word, p, pairs;

    res := 0;
    comb := firstcomb(NA+NB, NA);

    while type(comb, `set`) do
        word :=
        [seq(`if`(p in comb, A, B), p=1..NA+NB)];

        pairs := 0;
        for p to NA+NB-1 do
            if word[p] = B and word[p+1] = B then
                pairs := pairs + 1;
            fi;
        od;

        if type(pairs, `even`) then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;

        comb := nextcomb(comb, NA+NB);
    od;

    res;
end;

X :=
proc(NA, NB)
    1/2*binomial(NA+NB,NA)
    + 1/2*add(binomial(NA,q)*(-1)^(NB-q)*binomial(NB-2,q-2),q=0..NA)
    - 1/2*add(binomial(NA,q)*(-1)^(NB-q)*binomial(NB-2,q),q=0..NA);
end;


XX :=
proc(NA, NB)
    1/2*binomial(NA+NB,NA)
    + 1/2*(-1)^NB*
    add(binomial(NA+1,q)*(-1)^q*binomial(NB-1,q-1),q=0..NB);
end;


Very nice derivation. (+1)

Let's form the tri-variate generating function of these sequences. Let the variables $x$ and $y$ record the number of $A$'s and $B$ respectively and the variable $z$ record the number of consecutive pairs of $B$'s. Then we have that the sequences of length $n$ are enumerated by
$$g_n(x,y,z) := 
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
x & yz
\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This comes from counting with a state machine where state keeps track of the previous symbol. From the state A we go to itself with the weight $x$ and to the state B with weight $y$. And from the state B to A with $x$ and to itself with $yz$ (since then we get a consecutive pair of $B$'s).
The generating function is the sum of all these, so let's sum over $n$ (we don't get the empty string but that doesn't matter). We get
$$
g(x,y,z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(x,y,z) \\
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y
\end{pmatrix}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
x & yz
\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} \\
= \frac{1}{1-x-xy-yz+xyz}
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1-yz & y \\
x & 1-x
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} \\
= \frac{x+y+yx-xyz}{1-x-xy-yz+xyz}.
$$
Expanding the denominator first by geometric sum and then by binomial theorem yields
$$
g = 
(x+y+yx-xyz)\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{|\alpha|=m} \binom{m}{\alpha}(-1)^{\alpha_4} x^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_4}y^{\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4}z^{\alpha_3+\alpha_4}
$$
and extracting $\sum_{k \text{ even}}[x^{N_A}y^{N_B}z^k]$ leaves us with $4$ triple sums.
Update:
Infact we can do the following manipulation that results only in a single sum (or four of them because of the prefactor).
$$
\frac{1}{1-x-xy-yz+xyz}
= \frac{1}{1-yz} \frac{1}{1-(1+\frac{y}{1-yz})x}.
$$
Exctract $[x^{N_A}]$ and we're left with
$$
\frac{1}{1-yz} \left( 1 + \frac{y}{1-yz} \right)^{N_A}
= \sum_{k=0}^{N_A} \binom{N_A}{k} \frac{y^k}{(1-yz)^{k+1}}
$$
Extraction of $y$ then yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N_A} \binom{N_A}{k} \binom{N_B}{N_B-k} z^{N_B-k}
$$
Yes, this works. And we have the single sum solution:
Solution
Let's define the helper function
$$
h(a,b,c) = \sum_{k=0}^a \binom{a}{k} \binom{b}{k} {\large 1}_{b-k \equiv c \pmod 2}
$$
The answer is then given by
$$
h(N_A-1, N_A, 0) + h(N_A, N_A-1, 0) + h(N_A-1, N_B-1, 0) - h(N_A-1, N_B-1, 1).
$$

﻿Contents

Overview
General Discussion Of Pertinent Stars and Bars Theory
Derivation of Helper Function $~h(N_A,N_B,w,o)$
Upper and Lower Bounds of $~w~$ and $~o~$
Closed Form Formula For $~f(M)$


$\underline{\text{Overview}}$
This answer uses Stars and Bars theory, in a complicated manner, to obtain a closed form formula for $~f(M),~$ which represents the number of words of length $~M = N_A + N_B~$ that have an even number of consecutive B-pairs.
For Stars and Bars theory, see this article and this article.
Let $~g(N_A,N_B)~$ denote the number of words that have an even number of consecutive B-pairs, based on the variables $~N_A,N_B.~$
Clearly, for a specific value of $~M,~ N_A~$ must be some element in $~\{0,1,\cdots,M\}.~$
Therefore,
$$f(M) = \sum_{N_A = 0}^M g(N_A, ~M-N_A). \tag1 $$
Therefore, the entire problem reduces to deriving the closed form formula for $~g(N_A, ~N_B).$

$\underline{\text{General Discussion Of Pertinent Stars and Bars Theory}}$
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{M}{N_B} = \binom{N_A + N_B}{N_B}~$ different ways of constructing a string of length $~M~$ that has $~N_B~$ B's.
What is needed is some way of partitioning these $~\displaystyle \binom{M}{N_B}~$ strings into mutually exclusive groups, where each group has the same number of consecutive B pairs.
Throughout this section, for illustrative purposes, assume that $~N_A = 7,~$ and $~N_B = 20.~$ Now, consider the following tableau.
_ A _ A _ A _ A _ A _ A _ A _

The $~7~$ A's create $~(7+1)~$ islands.  Reading the islands from left to right, let the variables $~x_1, \cdots, x_8~$ denote the respective sizes of these islands.
Assume that of these $~8~$ variables that:

$w~$ of these variables are $~\geq 2.~$
$o~$ of these variables are equal to $~1.$
Then, it is to be understood that exactly $~8 - w - o~$ of these variables are $~= 0.$

Since $~x_1 + \cdots + x_8 = N_B = 20,~$ you have that the sum of the $~w~$ variables is $~20 - o.~$
Suppose that $~x_i~$ is one of these $~w~$ variables.  Then, the number of consecutive B pairs in the corresponding island is $~x_i - 1.~$
Therefore, the total number of consecutive B pairs, based on the values of $~w~$ and $~o~$ is $20 - w - o.$
Suppose that you have a specific group of 20 B's distributions, where each distribution has exactly $~w~$ of the $~8~$ variables $~\geq 2,~$ and exactly $~o~$ of the variables that are $~= 1.$
If $~20 - w - o~$ is odd, then this group should be ignored.
Alternatively, if $~20 - w - o~$ is even, then the group needs to be enumerated.
So, $~g(7,20)~$ will represent the sum of the enumerations of all of the groups where $~20 - w - o~$ is even.

$\underline{\text{Derivation of Helper Function} ~h(N_A,N_B,w,o)}$
Assume that $~N_A~$ and $~N_B~$ are fixed constants.  Consistent with the illustration in the previous section:

Let $~x_1, \cdots, x_{(N_A + 1)}~$ represent the corresponding variables.

Consider the subset of the $~\displaystyle \binom{N_A + N_B}{N_B}~$ distributions that result in exactly $~w~$ of the variables being $~\geq 2,~$ and exactly $~o~$ of the variables $~= 1.~$

Define $~h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~)~$ as:

$~0 ~: ~N_B - w - o~$ is odd.
Else, the number of elements in the pertinent subset of the $~\displaystyle \binom{N_A + N_B}{N_B}~$ distributions.



The next section will establish upper and lower bounds for each of the variables $~w~$ and $~o,~$ based on the (fixed) values of $~N_A~$ and $~N_B.$
So, you have that
$$g( ~N_A, ~N_B) = \sum_{w ~\text{is in range}}
\left[ ~\sum_{o ~\text{is in range}} ~h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~)~\right].$$
So, in this section, it only remains to derive $~h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~).$
Derivation:
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{N_A + 1}{w} \times \binom{N_A + 1 - w}{o}~$ ways of selecting the $~w~$ variables, and then selecting the $~o.~$ variables.
Now, assume that (reading the variables from left to right), the first $~w~$ variables are $~\geq 2,~$ and the next $~o~$ variables are $~= 1.~$
Then, the number of pertinent distributions will correspond to the number of solutions to

$x_1 + \cdots + x_w + y_1 + \cdots + y_o = N_B.$
$x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_w \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$
$y_1, ~\cdots, ~y_o = 1.~$

Since $~y_1, ~\cdots, ~y_o~$ each have a fixed value, the above enumeration is equivalent to enumerating the number of solutions to

$x_1 + \cdots + x_w = N_B - o.$
$x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_w \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$

Basic Stars and Bars theory requires that each variable have a lower bound of $~0.~$  This is easily accommodated by the change of variables $~z_i = x_i - 2 ~:  i \in \{1,2,\cdots,w\}.$
Therefore you are now enumerating the number of solutions to

$z_1 + \cdots + z_w = N_B - o - 2w.$
$z_1, ~\cdots, ~z_w \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Basic Stars and Bars theory, the enumeration is
$$\binom{[ ~N_B - o - 2w ~] + [w - 1]}{w-1} = \binom{N_B - o - w - 1}{w-1}.$$
Therefore, $~h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~)~$ equals

$0 ~: ~N_B - w - o~$ is odd.

else $~\displaystyle \binom{N_A + 1}{w} \times \binom{N_A + 1 - w}{o} \times \binom{N_B - o - w - 1}{w-1}.$



$\underline{\text{Upper and Lower Bounds of} ~w ~\text{and} ~o}$
Assume that $~N_A, N_B~$ are fixed elements in $~\Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
The boundaries for $~w~$ will be based on $~N_A~$ and $~N_B,~$ and the boundaries for $~o~$ will be based on $~N_A, ~N_B, ~$ and $~w.$
For $~\textbf{w}$:
It is harmless to require that $~w \geq 1,~$ since if $~w = 0,~$ then there can not be any instance of consecutive B's.  Note that regardless of the values of $~N_A~$ and $~N_B,~$ you can always have (for example) $~w = 1,~$ with the corresponding variable $~= N_B~$ (unless $~N_B < 2$). Therefore $~w \geq 1~$ is always a satisfactory lower bound for $~w.$
To establish the upper bound for $~w,~$ there are several considerations:

$w~$ must be $~\leq N_A + 1,~$ since that is the total number of variables.
Since the minimum value of each of the $~w~$ variables is $~2, ~w~$ must be $~\leq \displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{N_B}{2}\right\rfloor.$
Further, since the max value of $~w~$ occurs when $~o = 0,~$ and since one of the factors (from the previous section) of $~h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~)~$ is  $~\displaystyle \binom{N_B - o - w - 1}{w-1},~$ you must have that $N_B - w - 1 \geq w - 1 \iff N_b \geq 2w.$  This added constraint may be ignored, since it is automatically satisfied by the previous bullet point.

Therefore,

$w \geq 1.$
$\displaystyle w \leq \min\left( ~N_A + 1,  ~\left\lfloor \frac{N_B}{2}\right\rfloor ~\right).$

For $~\textbf{o}$:
Analysis of the bounds on the variable $~o~$ is similar.  Since $~w \geq 1,~$ and you can have one variable $~= N_{B},~$ you can always have $~o = 0.$
When $~N_B - w - o~$ is even,
$$h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~) = \binom{N_A + 1}{w} \times \binom{N_A + 1 - w}{o} \times \binom{N_B - o - w - 1}{w-1}.$$
Therefore, you must have that

$o \leq N_A + 1 - w.$
$o \leq N_B - 2w.$

Therefore,

$o \geq 0.$
$\displaystyle o \leq \min\left( ~N_A + 1 - w,  ~N_B - 2w ~\right).$


$\underline{\text{Closed Form Formula For} ~~f(M)}$
$~h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~)~$ equals

$0 ~: ~N_B - w - o~$ is odd.

else $~\displaystyle \binom{N_A + 1}{w} \times \binom{N_A + 1 - w}{o} \times \binom{N_B - o - w - 1}{w-1}.$


Boundaries:

$w \geq 1.$
$\displaystyle w \leq \min\left( ~N_A + 1,  ~\left\lfloor \frac{N_B}{2}\right\rfloor ~\right).$
$o \geq 0.$
$\displaystyle o \leq \min\left( ~N_A + 1 - w,  ~N_B - 2w ~\right).$

$$g( ~N_A, ~N_B) = \sum_{w ~\text{is in range}}
\left[ ~\sum_{o ~\text{is in range}} ~h( ~N_A, ~N_B, ~w, ~o ~)~\right].$$
$$f(M) = \sum_{N_A = 0}^M g(N_A, ~M-N_A). $$
